# Новые слова в современном русском языке

Tags: неологизм

Я уже говорил ранее о редком старинном слове *прекраса*, которое возродилось ныне (не без помощи инета) в таком выражении как **прекрасы нашего города**. В наше время словотворчеством в сети занимаются многие тысячи и тысячи пользователей сети. Придумаешь какое-нибудь слово, проверишь в поиске : уже есть! Все уже придумали до нас)))
Буквально несколько минут назад пришло на ум **вражество**. В Нацкорпусе единственный пример :

> Л. К. Чуковская. Спуск под воду (1949-1957) На чем же лучше определяется **дружество и вражество**, даль и близость, если не на том, какие стихи и какие строки в этих стихах ты любишь?

За несколько веков русской литературы только одному автору втемяшилось в голову это слово! Заглянув в сегодняшнее виртуальное окошко, нашел десятки новых примеров *вражества*, вот один из них (чей-то девиз) :

> **И дружество, и вражество**,
> Пока мой путь со мной,
> И нищенство, и княжество
> Ценю ценой одной.

Тоже стихи :

> Эта жизнь – и мне, и тебе,
> В ней **вражество и друг**, в ней мужество и
> страх,
> Так шагай навстречу судьбе в дырявых
> башмаках.
> В эту жизнь нырни с головой,
> К поверхности со дна, барахтаясь, плыви,
> Ни король, ни маг, ни герой, а все-таки –
> живи.
> http://achilova.narod.ru/texts/boots.htm

Как вы уже догадались, ни в одном словаре этого самого вражества нет и никогда не было. Антоним к содружеству, это достаточно очевидное слово, оно легко вычисляется сегодняшними поэтами, романтиками и любителями многочисленных ролевых игр, где *темное вражество* является неотъемлимым атрибутом.
Если вы, уважаемые форумчане, встретили на просторах рунета НОВЫЕ СТАРЫЕ СЛОВА, отпишитесь! Или вдруг сами придумали, что вдвойне интересно.
Дерзкий grumant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Народ дружно набрал в рот воды, но это не страшно, ибо у каждого имеются свои повседневные заботы.
Вот интересная статья Михаила Эпштейна на затронутую мной тему -  " Русский язык: система и свобода", рекомендую к прочтению.
http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=1.40

Необходимо  хотя бы частично восстановить утраченную русскую лексику (десятки тысяч слов!), придать старым словам новое звучание и значение. "Изобретать" новые слова - также очень увлекательное и достойное занятие для любителей великого и могучего, который переживает далеко не лучшие времена : литература в явном упадке.
Давно позабытое слово :

> **ЛЮ́БОСТЬ**, и, ж. Чувство любви, дружелюбия. Их <дев> на-Лицѣ Красота, и-Приятность, и-вся Миловидность, Купно и-Лю́бости всѣж совокупно играя сияли. Трд. Тилем. I 62.

Источник - http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/

Слова *любость* нет в современных академических словарях, но оно есть в мыслях людей.
Примеры новейшего использования **любости** в текстах :

> **Девица лен трепала**
> Вот уж как поутру
> Девица лён трепала,
> Лён трепала,
> Стебельки мяла!
> "Ты треплись, треплись,
> Мой лён-батюшка,
> Помоги сыскать
> Мово милова!
> А мой милый друг
> Нынче в городе,
> Вдруг забыл меня
> Да привет не шлёт...
> Напряду я льна,
> Буду ткать холсты,
> Холсты ровные,
> С бахромой края!
> Намочу в слезах,
> Отбелю щёлоком
> Да скрою-пошью
> Я рубаху милому!
> Ту рубаху в городе
> Он наденет с поясом,
> С красным поясом,
> С угрызением!
> Вспомнит друг
> Мои косы длинные,
> Речи плавные,
> Голос ласковый,
> **Вспомнит он наши любости**,
> Мои руки тяжёлые,
> Взгляд прищуренный!

Другой автор :

> Знать витала недаром
> Неба ломкая просинь...
> Как бесценный подарок
> Эта тёплая осень...
> Что за **дивная любость**:
> Я забылся словами -
> Твои нежные губы
> Так меня целовали.

http://www.neizvestniy-geniy.ru/cat/literature/stihi/156571.html

Русская лексика не должна пропадать бесследно, о ней нужно заботиться. Иначе останутся только *рэп, драйв, тренд и ароматерапия*...

Answer (score 2):

Сегодня встретила одно интересное слово на форуме. Актуальное для надвигающегося Нового года - ОПОДАРИТЬ. Мне кажется, что я его и раньше встречала, но не уверена.

Мне кажется, что это слово по значению нечто среднее, между "одарить" и "подарить", смесь этих двух слов.

Comment: Мне не очень нравится. Слышится в нем какое-то безразличие по сравнению с  подарить и одарить: обилетить, оподарить...

Answer (score 2):

Мне такие слова нравятся - в них чувствуется свежая образность, они как новые зеленые листочки на старом дереве. И еще они похожи на новые краски, прекрасно дополняющие нашу обычную палитру слов и выражений.Эти слова многомерны и неоднозначны уже при своем создании: они сами по себе могут выразить аромат времени,  особенность и неповторимость чувства, а также ту среду, тот класс людей, в которой и для которой они созданы.

И в то же время не хотелось бы, чтобы они входили в официальные словари. Для подобных слов было бы  желательно всенародно создать особый художественный словарь, вроде народной википедии особенных (художественных или разговорно-бытовых) слов. А дальше у каждого слова будет своя судьба - главное, чтобы они не затерялись во времени. Возможно, такой словарь стал бы источником обновления и нашей обычной речи.